# Deletion of pointer to incomplete type and smart pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, auto-ptr

When trying to use an `auto_ptr` with a type that was declared with forward-declaration, like this:

```
class A;
...
std::auto_ptr<A> a;
```

the destructor of `A` is not called (apparently, because `auto_ptr` internally `delete`s the underlying pointer and the destructor for an incomplete type cannot be called).

However, the same code works fine and the destructor is called when using `std::shared_ptr` instead of `std::auto_ptr`.
How can that be explained?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A `shared_ptr` can be declared with an incomplete type, yes.  The type does not need to be complete until you initialize or reset it.

When you initialize or reset a `shared_ptr` to point to a new object, it creates a "deleter" that can be used to destroy the object.  For example, consider the following:

```
// somewhere where A is incomplete:
std::shared_ptr<class A> p;

// define A
class A { /* ... */ };

p.reset(new A());
```

When you call `reset`, `A` is complete because you're creating an instance of it using `new`.  The `reset` function creates and stores internally a deleter that will be used to destroy the object using `delete`.  Because `A` is complete here, that `delete` will do the right thing.

By doing this, `shared_ptr` does not require that `A` be complete when the `shared_ptr<A>` is declared; it only requires that `A` is complete when the `shared_ptr` constructor that takes a raw pointer is invoked or when you call `reset` with a raw pointer.

Note that if `A` is *not* complete when you do one of those two things, `shared_ptr` won't do the right thing and the behavior is undefined (this is explained in [the documentation for `boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#Members), which is probably the best resource for learning how to use `shared_ptr` correctly, regardless which version of `shared_ptr` you are using (Boost, TR1, C++0x, etc.)).

However, as long as you always follow the best usage practices for `shared_ptr`--notably, if you always initialize and reset a `shared_ptr` directly with a pointer resulting from a call to `new`--you won't have to worry about violating this rule.

This functionality isn't free:  `shared_ptr` has to create and store a pointer to the deleter functor; typically this is done by storing the deleter as part of the block that stores the strong and weak reference counts or by having a pointer as part of that block that points to the deleter (since you can provide your own deleter).

`auto_ptr` (and `unique_ptr` too) is designed to be free of any overhead:  operations on it are supposed to be just as efficient as using a dumb pointer.  Thus, `auto_ptr` doesn't have this functionality.

Comment: Here is a summary of the completeness requirements for both unique_ptr and shared_ptr:  http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/incomplete.html

Comment: For one hour of highly entertaining material on shared_ptr, check out [STL on STL](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Advanced-STL-1-of-n). Also worth mentioning `std::make_shared<T>`.

Comment: Thanks!  Here is an updated link for  the summary of the completeness requirements for both unique_ptr and shared_ptr: http://howardhinnant.github.io/incomplete.html