# Pimpl with unique_ptr : Why do I have to move definition of constructor of interface to ".cpp"?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, pimpl-idiom

The code would work file as long as I don't move the definition of constructor (of `B`) to the header `B.h`.

**B.h**

```
class Imp;  //<--- error here
class B{
    public:
    std::unique_ptr<Imp> imp;
    B();     //<--- move definition to here will compile error
    ~B();
    //// .... other functions ....
};
```

**B.cpp**

```
#include "B.h"
#include "Imp.h"
B::B(){ }
~B::B(){ }
```

**Imp.h**

```
class Imp{};
```

**Main.cpp**  (compile me)

```
#include "B.h"
```

> Error: deletion of pointer to incomplete type
>   Error: use of undefined type 'Imp' C2027

I can somehow understand that the destructor must be moved to `.cpp`, because destructure of `Imp` might be called :-

```
delete pointer-of-Imp;  //something like this
```

However, I don't understand **why the rule also covers constructor** (question).

I have read :-

- [Deletion of pointer to incomplete type and smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606750/deletion-of-pointer-to-incomplete-type-and-smart-pointers)
  describes reason why destructor need to be in `.cpp`.
- [std::unique_ptr with an incomplete type won't compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954518/stdunique-ptr-with-an-incomplete-type-wont-compile)
  warns about the default destructor.

Comment: It's the *destructor* that matters.

Comment: @Kerrek SB   the constructor does not matters?

Comment: Can't [reproduce](http://rextester.com/JOLBY45666)

Comment: @WhiZTiM  I believe it has to be in different files.  Your test case have definition of "Imp", so there will be no error.  In my test case, "Main.cpp" doesn't include "Imp.h".

Comment: @Dan I can't, because my objective is to use Pimpl-idiom.   ... or I misunderstand what you stated?

Comment: Try it :-) The point is that you must have the destructor definiton out-of-line, otherwise the destructor obviously needs access to the complete type `Imp`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The constructor needs to destroy the class members, in the case that it exits by exception.

I don't think that making the constructor `noexcept` would help, though maybe it should.

Comment: @javaLover Buried deep in the compiler. If a member constructor throws, the previous members (in declaration order) are destroyed. If the constructor body throws, all the members are destroyed.

Answer (score -2):

Preprocessed out of b.cpp can be generated by following command,
`g++ -E b.cpp >> b.preprocessed`
And it is as follows,

```
# 1 "b.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "b.cpp"
# 1 "b.h" 1

class Imp;

class B
{
    std::unique_ptr< Imp> imp;
public:
    B(){}
    ~B();
};
# 2 "b.cpp" 2
# 1 "imp.h" 1

class Imp
{
};
# 3 "b.cpp" 2

B::~B(){}
```

It is clearly visible here, declaration of `class Imp` comes after constructor.
So how constructor can create something which doesn't exist for it? (Only forward declaration is not enough) and It makes clear that constructor definition must be in `b.cpp` file so that it will come after `class Imp` declaration and it becomes complete type.
Other point is, i don't think it is the correct way of using pimple-idiom. Implementation class should be declared and defined in source file which is not accessible from outside rather then keeping it in separate header file.